# Obtaining NDVI data only for imagery within an imported polygon

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, naip

I am trying to visualize NDVI for a specific boundary that I have imported from ArcMap. 
When I filter the NAIP imagery by the boundary it works perfectly, but when I try and filter the MODIS by the boundary I only receive an output of the NDVI values for the entire dataset (world). This causes problems later on when I need to use the .map function to add the 'NDVI' band to the clipped Naip imagery.

Below is a segment of my code where geom references the imported polygon.

I am new to Google Earth Engine.

```
var geom = table2 
var naip = ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ")
  .filterDate('2011-07-03','2011-08-12')
  .filterBounds(geom);
Map.addLayer(naip);
var mod = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A2")
  .filterDate('2011-07-03','2011-08-12')
  .filterBounds(geom)
  .select('NDVI'); 
Map.addLayer(mod);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ee.ImageCollection.mosaic()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.imagecollection.mosaic) to convert your image collection to an image, and [ee.Image.clip()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.image.clip) to clip the image to a specified geometry/polygon. For example:

```js
// Define an example geometry.
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point(-121.646, 43.762).buffer(1e4);
Map.centerObject(geom);

var naip = ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ")
  .filterDate('2011-07-03','2011-08-12');
Map.addLayer(naip.mosaic().clip(geom), {}, 'naip');

var mod = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A2")
  .filterDate('2011-07-03','2011-08-12')
  .select('NDVI'); 
Map.addLayer(mod.mosaic().clip(geom), {min:0, max:10000}, "modis");
```

Note that `.filterBounds()` is not needed if all you are going to do is visualize the results, although it doesn't hurt to include it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this without buffering a point? I imported a polygon boundary I would like to clip the image to.